# Override or add some style properties in WPF

Tags: wpf, styles

I am porting a Bootstrap theme to WPF and faced a problem: I can't change some properties using additional style for StackPanel. I have ResourceDictionary containing `BtnBase` base style and `BtnPrimary`, `BtnSecondary` etc. All of them were inherited from `BtnBase` and contain only color properties. `BtnBase` does not contain any `margin` rule. When I try to add `margin` rule for a current StackPanel, there is no effect. I read about styles and knew that more than one style can't be applied, styles in ResourceDictionary have higher priority and I should use `BasedOn`. But I need to copy and paste my style in the `StackPanel` and replace `BasedOn` for each button variant. Is there a way to bypass it and add `margin` property for all styles?

code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="32">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BtnBase}>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,10,0"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnPrimary}" Content="Primary" />
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnSecondary}" Content="Secondary" />
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnSuccess}" Content="Success" />
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnInfo}" Content="Info" />
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnWarning}" Content="Warning" />
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnDanger}" Content="Danger" />
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnLight}" Content="Light" />
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnDark}" Content="Dark" />
    </StackPanel>
```

[image: Buttons]

Comment: When you manually set the style like you do for each button then the style in Stackpanel.Resouces is not applied. If you remove the style part of each button, then the style in Stackpanel.Resource will apply to all buttons.

Comment: Seems to me that all styles are the same except for the background. Make one style with all the properties which are the same, and set the background of each button.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada No, there are many colors, background, hover background, mouse pressed background and so on. Totally 8 colors for each button style

Comment: And you cannot add the margin property to those styles ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I need a custom margin only for buttons in this StackPanel. In other containers it might be different. My styles are just a skin.

Comment: `<Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnDark}" Content="Dark" Margin=""0,0,10,0 />` Why over complicate things ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada because there may be much more buttons, labels, etc. By setting ResourceDictionary styles I made almost impossible to apply "local" mini styles for specific conditions

Comment: Then there is only one option left, create other Styles and base them on BtnPrimary, BtnSecondary, etc...

Comment: can you please give any feedback to my suggestion, @ZelDa?

Answer (score 0):

You can treat all buttons as Items in ListBox.

ListBox will create a ListBoxItem for each Button, and you can add Margin to those ListBoxItems, using `ItemContainerStyle`. That doesn't modify Buttons styles, but creates same effect.

In ItemContainerStyle I also change ListBoxItem template to undo hover, selection colors, etc, which can change appearance - just plain ContentPresenter is left.

ItemsPanel by default is vertical StackPanel, but I changed ItemsPanel and layout to horizontal StackPanel.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="32"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnPrimary}" Content="Primary" />
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnSecondary}" Content="Secondary" />
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnSuccess}" Content="Success" />
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnInfo}" Content="Info" />
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnWarning}" Content="Warning" />
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnDanger}" Content="Danger" />
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnLight}" Content="Light" />
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnDark}" Content="Dark" />
</ListBox>
```